# Katalon integration with gitlab

Tags: gitlab, katalon-studio

I have created a project in Gitlab and then enbled the git integration in katalon studio.
Then while trying to clone the project, getting the following error.
Could you please help me to solve this issue and let em know if you any more information on this..

[image: ta]

Answer (score 1):

Enabling git integration might not be enough.

According to this [guide](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/continuous_integration_gitlab.html) which you have to read, in order to integrate Gitlab you have to download and setup a GitLab runner.

In your specific case, however, it sounds more like a network issue. Assuming you checked that URL is correct, and that you are connected to internet and everything, you might try the following git command (see also [this](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/git-integration.html#clone-a-katalon-studio-project-from-a-git-repository)):

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

<sub>Note: this forces git to use https authentication in **all** your repos. If this unblocks you, I'd strongly suggest to revert to ssl and disable it only for your cloned repo.</sub>